# Babel doesn't process node_modules - no excludes, no .babelrc

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

This has been asked multiple times, and the issues always comes down to either a presence of `exclude` in babel config, or babel config being in `.babelrc` instead of `babel.config.json`. In my case it's something else. Here's my `babel.config.json`:

```json
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      {
        "runtime": "automatic"
      }
    ],
    "@babel/env"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "alias": {
          "@common": "./src/common",
          "@files": "./src/files",
          "@settings": "./src/settings",
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Here's my `webpack.config.js`

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const ENV = process.env;
const scriptDir = path.join(__dirname, 'scripts');

const config = {
  devtool: ENV.WEBPACK_DEVTOOL || 'eval-source-map',

  mode: 'development',

  entry: {
    app: ['./src/app.js'],
  },

  output: {
    path: scriptDir,
    publicPath: '/',
  },

  target: ['web', 'es5'],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/ajv'),
        use: 'null-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|cjs|jsx)$/,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/nanoid')],
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        use: ['json-loader'],
        type: 'javascript/auto',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.min\.js$/,
        exclude: [/react/, /node_modules/],
        use: ['script-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /node_modules\/vfile\/core\.js/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'imports-loader',
            options: {
              type: 'commonjs',
              imports: ['single process/browser process'],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV.NODE_ENV),
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    symlinks: false,
    modules: [path.join(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules'],
    alias: {
      '@common': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/common'),
      '@files': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/files'),
      '@settings': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/settings'),
    },
    fallback: {fs: false, path: require.resolve('path-browserify')},
  },
};

if (ENV.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  config.devtool = 'hidden-source-map';
  config.mode = 'production';
}

if (ENV.WEBPACK_PLUGIN) {
  const Plugin = require(ENV.WEBPACK_PLUGIN);
  config.plugins.push(new Plugin());
}

module.exports = config;
```

When I run the output bundle in IE11, I'm seeing an arrow function, and it comes specifically from package [nanoid](https://github.com/ai/nanoid). As you see above, I tried to explicitly `include` it. Tried without the `include` as well.

I'm on Babel 7.12 and Webpack 5.4.

So what is still missing in the config? Why is babel still refusing to parse (some of the) `node_modules`?

Comment: Are you sure `nanoid` is directly in `path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/nanoid')` and not in some nested `node_modules`? Might be worth trying `/\/node_modules\/nanoid\//` instead to match any nesting level.

Comment: Looking at `yarn.lock` looks like `nanoid` is a subdependency of just one package, but I'll definitely give your suggestion a try @loganfsmyth. I'm not sure why I'd need to use `include` at all though. From what I see in the docs, babel is supposed to just go through all the `node_modules`.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Tried your string, didn't make a difference...

Comment: In fact there are many other instances of es6 code in the bundle, other than `nanoid`.

Comment: So to be clear, if you remove the `include` line entirely, you still get ES6 in the output? Could you post a sample piece of your Webpack bundle to show what you are seeing? One thing to try would be to put a JSON syntax error in your `babel.config.json` and make sure it errors when you build so you know Babel is actually trying to run.

Comment: @loganfsmyth - completely removing `include` works, so my problem is solved, thanks! `include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')]` also works.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution to the issue. I suggest you post your solution as an answer for this thread and try to mark your own answer as an answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was either to remove the `include` as suggested by @loganfsmyth in the comments above, or to set `include` to something more general:

```js
include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')]
```